# Java - Object from a string in ajax

Tags: java, ajax, generics

I am building a website and I have several different sections like guides movies etc. They all should have a like button.

So if the like button is pressed I want to increment the number of likes in the DB.

I have different DB models like `UserGuides`, `Movies` etc and I want to have a generic AJAX function.

this means:

If the user is on a guide and he presses "like" I want to update the like integer on a UserGuide etc.

I achieved it like this.

In the AJAX post I defined the class as a string that I want to update, for example `{obj: "UserGuides"}` if I want to update a UserGuide.

Now I have one AJAX handler that handles all my requests.

public static Result like() throws UnknownHostException, MongoException,
            DbAuthException {

```
    Map<String, String[]> map = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
    String username = map.get("username")[0];
    String title = map.get("title")[0];
    String obj = map.get("obj")[0];

    if (username.equals("") || title.equals("") || obj.equals("")) {
        return badRequest();
    }
    if (obj.equals("UserGuides")) {
        ajaxLike(UserGuides.class, new UserGuides(), username, title);
        return ok();
    }
    return badRequest();
```

So I check if the "class name" matches and if yes I call my generic function.

```
if (obj.equals("UserGuides")) {
                ajaxLike(UserGuides.class, new UserGuides(), username, title);
            }
```

Now I would obviously have to do this for all my classes. But the advantage would be that I would only need one handler.

Now my generic function looks like this

```
private static <T> void ajaxLike(Class<T> objClass, T obj, String username,
            String title) throws UnknownHostException, MongoException,
            DbAuthException {

        Datastore ds = getDatabase();
        Query<T> q = ds.createQuery(objClass).field("title").equal(title);
        UpdateOperations<T> submitUpdate = ds.createUpdateOperations(objClass)
                .inc("likes");
        ds.update(q, submitUpdate);
        ds.ensureIndexes();

    }
```

- It works fine atm but is this good practice?
- Do you see any potential errors?
- Are there better approaches?

Answer (score 1):

```
String username = map.get("username")[0];
```

If map does not have username, you will get a NPE there. Similarly else where too..

Comment: Well its impossible to get an NPE with my AJAX request. Should I still check it?

Comment: You should check it unless you like getting NPE's.

Comment: Well I just checked it. It seems that if I try to access the element it is ALWAYS null `String adsasdad= map.get("adsasdad")[0]` I always can access it, the value is just null.

Comment: @Klein It's always good to validate the params in the service layer. In the service layer you should not pay attention to the fact "there will always be a username in the ajax request". services do not depend on the layers above them to work perfectly.